# Select column based on variable in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL in C# in my application. I need to be able to select a column of a row, depending upon a variable. This is easy for the row as it's a simple where clause, but I'm at a loss with only selecting a specific column. Here is my code so far:

```
var permissions = (from s in dc.Permissions where s.dashboardname == permission select s.[variablehere]).Single();
```

Is this easy to accomplish?

Comment: You might want also to look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214881/using-lambda-expression-to-select-different-fields-from-field-names/4214894#4214894)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to change your database structure so that your columns becomes rows? (Pivot your table?)

Eg.

```
Permissions Table
-----------------
Id
Dashboardname
Page1
Page2
Page3
...
```

and turn it into

```
Permissions Table
-----------------
Id
Dashboardname
Pagename
```

Then you could use the where clause to select the row you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question completely, so this might be a bit off. But could your problem perhaps be solved by using [the LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

> You can use the DynamicQuery library
>   against any LINQ data provider
>   (including LINQ to SQL, LINQ to
>   Objects, LINQ to XML, LINQ to
>   Entities, LINQ to SharePoint, LINQ to
>   TerraServer, etc).  Instead of using
>   language operators or type-safe lambda
>   extension methods to construct your
>   LINQ queries, the dynamic query
>   library provides you with string based
>   extension methods that you can pass
>   any string expression into.

See the above link for samples and downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is either possible or a good practice. Note that if the variable name is provided by user he or she can easily take all the data they want. Maybe you should try using enumeration and switch() clause?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the variable is not supplied by the user - the variable is just the pages name, and there is a column for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Say the class that holds the permissions is named `Permission`, you can define an extension method:

```
public static class PermissionExtensions
{
    public static object SelectProperty(this Permission obj, string variable)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperty(variable).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
}
```

You can use this in your query like this:

```
(from s in dc.Permissions where s.dashboardname == permission select s)
    .Single().SelectProperty(variable);
```

This doesn't select the property in the query but instead gets it from the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that came in my mind is to create table with key-value pairs i.e.

- dashboard
- key
- value

where primary key is `(dashboard, key)`.